# Ionic 4 meme gif

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, gif, animated-gif

I would like add a meme or gif in my app.
I find (https://giphy.com/) for gif or (https://api.imgflip.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ionic 4 is just a web-app when it comes to rendering images or videos or gifs.

All you need is to have valid gif file url and use **img** html tag to render it:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar color="primary">
        <ion-title>
            Ionic 4 template
        </ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

  <img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/WOwRUGNtWhp19Jaep0/giphy.gif">

</ion-content>
```

You can play around with this stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-4-template-cknhhj and if you have a particular question or a use case in which the gif does not work - please ask that new question providing full context.